# Spring 3.1 web application issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, illegalaccessexception

I was developing simple spring mvc app with one controller. when i deploy the war file, I am getting following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter from class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:61)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:42)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:44)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:42)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:95)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.<init>(HttpServletBean.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.<init>(FrameworkServlet.java:211)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<init>(DispatcherServlet.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you double-check all your Spring JARs have the same version?

Comment: Yes, all my spring jars are version 3.1.0.

Comment: One more thing I noticed is, if I change the spring version from 3.1.0 to 3.0.7, everything works fine. So it has something to do with spring's latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a classloader issue.  I've run into this before when I ran into conflicts arising from MyEclipse loading different jar files instead of the ones I thought were loaded by the application!

One way to check is to run [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look at the jar files that are loaded into memory and where they originated.

To get more specific with the error you are getting, I'm quoting from the [JVM 7 specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3) that lists that exact error in 5.4.3.1.:

5.3. Creation and Loading

At run time, **a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name (§4.2.1) and its defining class loader.** Each such class or interface belongs to a single run-time package. **The run-time package of a class or interface is determined by the package name and defining class loader of the class or interface.**

**5.4.3.1. Class and Interface Resolution**

To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference from D to a class or interface C denoted by N, the following steps are performed:

The defining class loader of D is used to create a class or interface denoted by N. This class or interface is C. The details of the process are given in §5.3.

Any exception that can be thrown as a result of failure of class or interface creation can thus be thrown as a result of failure of class and interface resolution.

If C is an array class and its element type is a reference type, then the symbolic reference to the class or interface representing the element type is resolved by invoking the algorithm in §5.4.3.1 recursively.

Finally, access permissions to C are checked:
**If C is not accessible (§5.4.4) to D, class or interface resolution throws an IllegalAccessError.**

This condition can occur, for example, if C is a class that was originally declared to be public but was changed to be non-public after D was compiled.

If steps 1 and 2 succeed but step 3 fails, C is still valid and usable. Nevertheless, resolution fails, and D is prohibited from accessing C.

To sum it all up, it sounds like the jar is from a different package, that is from another classloader.