# How can I solve 500 error?

Tags: java, spring

I am creating basic HelloWorld application in Spring MVC.

But it throws me error.
**Error**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToNumberConverterFactory from class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:129)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Feb 16, 2016 4:06:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToNumberConverterFactory from class org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:129)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.<init>(StandardServletEnvironment.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.createEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.getEnvironment(HttpServletBean.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have attached all file for your reference.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVC</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
 -->
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
    <!-- Default Handler Mapping -->
    <!-- Default Handler -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>

    <!-- Controller Mapping -->
    <bean name="/hello.do" class="org.gvp.HelloController"></bean>

    <!-- View Resolver Mapping -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package org.gvp;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController 
{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("test");
        mv.addObject("msg","Hii KEval");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

How can I solve error?

Comment: which webserver do you use?

Comment: If you're learning Spring MVC and this is a brand new project, i recommend to use `Spring Boot`. If you insist to use plain spring mvc, do not use the very old `AbstractController`.

Comment: do you have all spring libraries in matching versions? is it possible you have something in wrong version?

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat 8, JDK 1.8,Spring framework 4.2.4

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366842/spring-3-1-web-application-issue

Comment: +1 for [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). Theres also a nice [generator page](https://start.spring.io/) that makes the project creation easier for you!

Comment: @Keval check in folder where you deploy your app, are all spring jar files are in version 4.2.4.  i had similar issues, and it was caused by something pulling wrong version of library. then class loader load requested class from incorrect jar file